# can't run a MapReduce Job on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, symlink

I'm trying to run a mapreduce job took from the internet. This job takes in input a 'points.dat' file and makes a k-means clustering on it. It should produce a file 'centroids.dat' and a file with points matched to their own centroid. A couple of months this was working, but now i'm trying to re-execute on a new installation.

I made

```
bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ..//..//../home/<myusername>/Downloads/points.dat
```

Everything is fine and the file appears in the web service tool in the /user// path on hdfs . Jps is ok

The jar requests args:

```
<input> <output> <n clusters>
```

so i made

```
bin/hadoop jar ../../../home/<myusername>/Downloads/kmeans.jar /user/<myusername>/ /out 3
```

it creates a "centroids.dat" file in /user/ and a out/ directory. As much as i can understand it tries to re-read "centroids.dat" to execute. So it ends with some failures like

```
"failed creating symlink /tmp/hadoop-<myusername>/mapred/local/1466809349241/centroids.dat <- /usr/local/hadoop/centroids.dat
```

So java raise a FileNotFoundException

I tried to shorten the question as much as possible. If more info are needed, no problem for me

Comment: Just an idea, do you have the right to write files in your folder? Sometimes if you work on outside servers, this happens.

Comment: I'm working in local. However i'm not that expert in linux. How can i check it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to mention main class in your command

```
bin/hadoop jar kmeans.jar MainClass input output
```

Comment: in the main class i have

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if(args != 3) {
    System.err.println("Usage: KMeans <in> <out> <clusters_number>");
     System.exit(2);
    }

and if i put the name of the main class after the path it prints the "usage: Kmeans .... etc etc"